# winmm.dll volume drop when seeking mp3

Tags: c#, audio, winmm

Ive been playing around and learning how to use winmm.dll for the past few days and have a mostly working program but have run into an issue that I haven't been able to find a fix for. The issue I'm having is that after seeking the song some random amount of times (usually 10 - 20) the volume will drop fairly low, probably down to around 20% of the original. This will continue happening with the volume getting lower each time and some times returning to the original level. The actual volume factor set via the 'setaudio' command is still correct no matter how much it drops and can still be adjusted perfectly fine just at the lower levels. I have tested this on windows 7 and 10 with the issue persisting on both.

Seek Method:

```
public void Seek(ulong position) {
    if (isOpen && position <= Length && isPlaying) {
        string command = string.Format("seek {0} to {1}", alias, position);
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (!isPaused) {
            command = string.Format("play {0}{1}", alias, isLooping ? " repeat" : string.Empty);
            mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```

Volume Property:

```
public int Volume {
    set {
        if (isOpen && (value >= 0 && value <= 1000)) {
            string command = string.Format("setaudio {0} volume to {1}", alias, value);
            mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
    get {
        if (isOpen) {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(128);
            string command = string.Format("status {0} volume", alias);
            mciSendString(command, output, 128, IntPtr.Zero);
            return Convert.ToInt32(output.ToString());
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a track bar for seek with a few added features to allow click seeking and to avoid spam seek requests. This track bar is also updated by a timer to track progress of the song. The event handler methods are below.

```
private void tbTime_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        //Lock editing of bar value by timer
        isTimeEdit = true;

        //Save initial bar value
        timeValueStore = tbTime.Value;

        //Move bar value to clicked location
        double mouseNum = ((((double)e.X - 10.0d) / ((double)tbTime.Width - 20.0d)) * (tbTime.Maximum - tbTime.Minimum));
        tbTime.Value = Convert.ToInt32(mouseNum.MinMax(tbTime.Minimum, tbTime.Maximum));
    }
}

private void tbTime_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        //Seek to value if changed from saved value
        if (player != null && tbTime.Value != timeValueStore) {
            player.Seek((ulong)tbTime.Value * 1000u);
        }
        //Unlock editing of bar value by timer
        isTimeEdit = false;
    }
}
```

I am aware that I can set and get the volume with the waveOut set and get volume functions but prefer the 'setaudio' command as it doesn't change the program's volume mixer setting. I also intend to add error catching once this problem is sorted.

Also just in case it comes up, the MinMax method in the MouseDown event handler is an extension I wrote to constrain the value.

Comment: Pretty unlikely anybody can identify the underlying problem.  You are using an api that stone cold old, it dates back to Windows version 3.  Getting good audio drivers is never not a problem, the older and less used the feature the less likely it works flawlessly.  Media players use the modern api, Media Foundation.  Not exactly a C# friendly api but you can find a wrapper for it.  Like [this one](http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Alrighty. Thanks Hans, ill have to take a look at that.